Update state, object with arrays
I would like to know how I could update this state:
details: {id:{optionA: optionA,
optionB: optionB,
quantity:1
}}
It would be something like this:
details: [{ 1: {optionA: optionA, optionB: optionB, counter:1 }}, {2: {optionA: optionA, optionB: optionB, counter:3 }} ]
I want to be able to update the quantity from a value
Being able to solve the problem of updating a complex state

What have you tried? What's the issue did you meet?
